# Unix shell script command that creates symlinks on windows?

Tags: windows, shell, unix, symlink

Is there a unix shell script command that creates symlinks, that works on windows too? 
(not windows-specific command but one that works on a unix-like shell like git bash)

Basically what i'm trying to do is: a script that creates a set of symlinks. Most of my users use Macs, but some people run my application on a unix-like shell like git bash. What is happening is, windows or git bash is creating copies instead of symlinks.

I found windows-specific commands like mklink but if at all possible I want a script that works on windows and mac. Worst case i would have to create a windows script and a mac script but want to avoid doing that if at all possible.

Comment: On Windows you can use `mklink /J <target> <src>` command. But I don't know how to call it from Windows Bash ...

Answer (score -1):

To create a symlink, run

```
ln -s
```

```
   -s, --symbolic
          make symbolic links instead of hard links
```

It does work, as you can see

```
$ ln -s 'Lawrence of Arabia (1962).mp4' foo.mp4

$ ls -gG
total 2660377
lrwxrwxrwx  1         29 May 31 23:57 foo.mp4 -> Lawrence of Arabia (1962).mp4
-rwx------+ 1 2724222788 May 25 14:22 Lawrence of Arabia (1962).mp4
```

Source

[`ln(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln)

Comment: That is the command I currently use. However on windows (win 7, gitbash shell), it creates a copy instead of an actual symlink.

Comment: mkdir folder1
    cd folder1
    vi file1
    (type the word "Test" and quit vi)

    cd ..

    ln -s folder1 folder2
    cd folder2
    vi file1

    (change the word "Test" to "Test2" and quit vi)

    cat file1
    (displays Test 2)

    cd ../folder1
    cat file1

    (On Windows gitbash: displays Test. On Mac Terminal: displays Test 2 correctly)

Comment: Hey Steven, it is definitely creating a copy on windows gitbash! I tried doing it again, editing the symlinked file does not edit the original file.